# how would I implement js observer or publish/subscribe pattern for this scenario?

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem scenario.  My page uses SystemJS to load js modules. After SystemJS has loaded all of the js modules, all of the required js modules are available to call DataLoader.LoadData().

My page loads an external svg.  After the page has fully loaded the external svg, DataLoader.LoadData() needs to be called to perform manipulations on the svg elements:

```
<div id="divMapContainer"><object id="imgMap" data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload="DataLoader.LoadData();"></object>
```

So here's my problem:

If I use the onload="DataLoader.LoadData();" approach in the div above then there's no guarantee that SystemJS will have completed it's import of the required js modules.  In this scenario, DataLoader.LoadData() will fail because not all of the required js modules are available yet.

If I simply call the DataLoader.LoadData() after SystemJS has completed importing the required js modules then there's no guarantee that the svg import will have completed.  Since DataLoader.LoadData() performs manipulations on specific elements of the svg, this function will fail if the svg has not finished loading yet.

So what is the solution for managing this scenario?  It seems like maybe observer or publish/subscribe pattern?  Should jQuery.Callbacks be used for this?  I reviewed the jquery doc for this but for some reason the specific code solution is not clear to me for this.

========================================================================

Here's a start to a potential solution for this problem.

- When the imports have completed, the next then() can set LoadDataPreconditions.ImportsLoaded = true
- When the svg has loaded, it's onload() event can set LoadDataPreconditions.SvgLoaded = true

  var LoadDataPreconditions = 
  {
     ImportsLoaded : true,
     SvgLoaded : true
  }

Some type of onchange listener can be wired to LoadDataPreconditions to exec the following function whenever the LoadDataPreconditions object changes:

```
function LoadDataConditional()
{
   var importsLoaded = LoadDataPreconditions.ImportsLoaded;
   var svgLoaded = LoadDataPreconditions.SvgLoaded;
   if(importsLoaded && svgLoaded) DataLoader.LoadData;
}
```

Does this seem like a reasonable approach?  How would I implement this wireup?

Comment: Attach the event listener using JavaScript, in a place where you know you have already imported your libraries; something like `document.getElementById('imgMap').addEventListener('load', DataLoader.LoadData)` should work.

Comment: what about this approach?: https://jsbin.com/bumogufime/edit?html,output